# jquery validation not validating all forms

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Im using jquery validation and everything is working except 1 field. I have the following jquery below

```
$().ready(function() {
    $('#cForm').validate({
        rules: { 
            cFname: { required: true },
            cLname: { required: true },
            cEmail: { required: true },
            cMessage: { required: true }
        },
        messages: {
            cFname: { required: "Please enter your first name" },
            cLname: { required: "Please enter your last name" },
            cEmail: { required: "Please enter your email address", email: "Must be a valid email address" },
            cMessage: { required: "Please enter a message" }                    
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
           $("#cSubmit span").text("Processing...");
           $("#cSubmit").attr('btn-disabled', true);
           form.submit();
         },
        // Do not change code below
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    });
});
```

And here is my html markup

```
        <form id="cForm" name="cForm" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-right:5px;">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your first name" id="cFname" name="cfname">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-left:5px;">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your last name" id="cLname" name="cLname">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email address" id="cEmail" name="cEmail">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" placeholder="Write your message here" name="cMessage" id="cMessage" required></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button  href="https://collabbro-bvcxtds.c9.io/app/" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="cSubmit" id="cSubmit" role="button">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

the code validates everyone field except the `cFname` input which I dont know why. I tried changing the `id` and `name` attribute in the html but nothing appears to be working. What am i overlooking? Thanks for helping me become a better full stack developer :)

Comment: change `name="cfname"` to `name="cFname"` issue resolved https://jsfiddle.net/z0pk7pk4/7/

Comment: So youre telling me the typo gods did this to me......

Comment: post it as an answer and ill vote yours to it. THanks mate.

Comment: you are most welcome, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

found a typo in my `name` attribute. Corrected it to `name="cFname"` rather than `name="cfname"`

Comment: FYI - questions typically get closed when the issue was just a typo.  Might be best for you to delete it before it gets closed.

Comment: damn im unable 2 delete it.